# MVC custom error view issues when site is deployed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm seeing weird issues once a site is deployed. I have specified a custom error controller & view in the Global.asax.cs using the following:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
        var currentController = " ";
        var currentAction = " ";
        var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(
            new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));

        if (currentRouteData != null)
        {
            if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null 
                && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
            {
                currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            }

            if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null 
                && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
            {
                currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            }
        }

        var ex = Server.GetLastError();
        var controller = new ErrorController();
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        var action = "Index";

        if (ex is HttpException)
        {
            var httpEx = ex as HttpException;

            switch (httpEx.GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 404:
                    action = "NotFound";
                    break;

                // others if any
            }
        }

        if (ex is NisSessionExpiredException)
        {
            action = "SessionExpired";
        }

        httpContext.ClearError();
        httpContext.Response.Clear();
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex is HttpException 
            ? ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() 
            : 500;
        httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        routeData.Values["action"] = action;

        controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);
        ((IController)controller).Execute(
            new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
    }
```

That works fine locally, but once deployed on a server, when an error occurs it again uses the specified controller & action but it always returns:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' or its master was
>   not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The
>   following locations were searched: ~/Views/Draft/Error.aspx
>   ~/Views/Draft/Error.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx ~/Views/Draft/Error.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Draft/Error.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

instead of the expected errors (as you can see above the error view is supposed to give me detailed information of what the thrown exception is and also a call stack). In my understanding this view should have never been invoked (and also it is never invoked locally).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue it was as simple as adding in web.config the following line:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

It turned out that maybe global settings of IIS mandate those to be on or something of sorts, as I have previously not specified that.